# TensorFlow on M1 Mac

Tags: macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm trying to install Tensorflow on my M1 Mac. I've been following Jeff Heaton's most recent guidance (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DgWvU0p2bk and https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/tensorflow-install-conda-mac-metal-jul-2022.ipynb), but when I get to creating an environment in the 'conda env create -f tensorflow-apple-metal-conda.yml -n tensorflow' folder I get the following error:

'

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-apple-metal-conda.yml

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

`
Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong? Thanks, really appreciate any insight

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps mentioned in below link works for Mac M1:

https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/